# Add a network route from a program, not via the operating system

Tags: sockets, networking, gateway

I am writing a program (currently in Python, future is C++) that needs to send a request to a server that is on a different network section, behind a gateway. In order to do this in a Windows network, I manually have to add the route to this external network (as administrator!) using the 'route add' command of the operating system.
Like this:
`route add <destination_subnet> MASK 255.255.0.0 <gateway_address>`

My Python code to access this external server looks basically like this:

```
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) as sock:
  UDP_IP = "172.31.1.2"
  UDP_PORT = 34980       # 0x88A4
  sdo = <message in a network frame...>
  sock.sendto(bytes(sdo), (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
  data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
```

Now I do not want to manually setup the network route using the route command. Furthermore, I do not want to use administrative rights.

My question: **Is there a way to tell the socket module directly to use that specific gateway?** I did not find something like that and I fear, the routing functionality is part of the operating system.

Comment: "_Is there a way to tell the socket module directly to use that specific gateway?_" No. "_I fear, the routing functionality is part of the operating system."_ Yes.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.